# MKAnnotation view without map

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotation

[image]how to create a overlay on mapView but the mkannotationview is show with an image. i want hide map and only user current location will show with custom image.

Thanks  in advance

Comment: please upload screen shot ?

Comment: please check..
only MKAnnotation custom image (event Image)  is show mapview set hidden